# Octaves ability to store path

Tags: octave

I'm curious to find out how Octave handle paths to files.

In my case I have a folder that containes another folder called "indata" and then the actual *.m file I've created. I dont want all the files in the same folder since they contain raw data from loads of tests. And sometime I want to go back and have a look at the old measurments.

For instance. I've written a script that asks the user for wanted file to use by octave that looks like this:

```
prompt = {"Please specify the data you want to analyze"};

[fname,fpath] = uigetfile();

raw_indata = [fpath,fname];
```

when looking at fname and fpath everything is correct. The file is stored correctly. If I look in "raw_indata" I get the full path to the file. Great.

The problem is occuring now...

```
DSR_data = xlsread('raw_indata');
```

I've tried
xlsread("raw_indata");
xlsread(fpath,fname);

what am I missing... ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DSR_data = xlsread('raw_indata');
```

you're telling xls to read a file called "raw_indata". Literally.

You should be passing the `raw_indata` **variable** in instead. Without quotes.

```
DSR_data = xlsread(raw_indata);
```

Comment: just to add explanation for your other two failed input attempts: using double quotes did the same thing Tasos explained above. For most purposes, character arrays in Octave are the same whether created using ' or ". Using `xlsread(fpath,fname)` passes `fpath` and `fname` as separate inputs to xlsread, expecting the second input to specify either a worksheet or data range.  Had you put the inputs in brackets again, as `[fpath,fname]` it likely would have worked, as it would have concatenated the two strings as you did when you created `raw_indata`, and passed them as a path to `xlsread`,

Comment: Great! Thanks for the help!